# Using operator>> with a pointer to ifstream object

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, ifstream

Why in the following code is the instruction `os->operator>> input` wrong? Is not the return value of operator>> the object *os?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double input;
  ifstream * os = new ifstream("prova.dat");
  os->operator>> input;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use pointers to `ifstream`s! They're not intended to be used that way. They can be passed by reference where necessary.

Comment: @Rook what's the specific reason?

Comment: @RoyIacob The same as for any other object shouldn't be used via raw pointer references whenever avoidable.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `input` was a string. Either `os->operator>>(input)` or `*os >> input` works.

Comment: @RoyIacob: the standard classes have all been quite carefully written to handle their own resource creation and cleanup. By creating them on the heap, you lose all of the nice RAII facilities they provide you, you have to take your own responsibility for cleanup and various other things become harder to do. I can't think of any upsides to doing it at all.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to use `>>` as a method, then you need to pass arguments by `()` like normal functions. To dereference it you should use these two ways:

```
os->operator >> (input);
```

or

```
*os >> input;
```

Note: Why pointers, when you can use automatic objects or references. Moreover, you need to manage the allocated object and free it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating pointers to streams like that, you're probably doing something wrong.

This should work fine:

```
int main()
{
  double input;
  std::ifstream os("prova.dat");
  os >> input;
  return 0;
}
```

Because the `ifstream` was allocated on the stack, it will be automatically cleaned up when the function finishes, which will close the underlying filehandle. You missed the explicit `delete` you'd need to do the same in your code.

If you need to pass your stream around, you can do so by reference:

```
double read_double(std::ifstream& stream)
{
  double d;
  stream >> d;
  return d;
}

int main()
{
  std::ifstream os("prova.dat");
  double input = read_double(os);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's half an answer

Comment: @MooingDuck which half?

Comment: @Rook The half that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @0x499602D2, ahh, so you mean it really isn't any answer at all, and Mooing Duck didn't even manage half of a useful comment? The OP seemed like a standard "XY Problem" type question, and this seemed a reasonable response, instead of letting them continue to write code in an inadvisable way.

Comment: Right, but I think he was looking for an explanation for why his code didn't work. Telling him the recommended way is still good though.

Comment: Fair enough. MM at least has that bit covered, so the OP won't go away empty handed.